# Using MERGE to insert rows when matched?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using `MERGE` to insert records in a table but only if a column in the source satisfies a condition.

Is the following a valid `MERGE` statement:

```
    MERGE INTO sometable AS [Target] USING
    (
        --Here SELECT and INNER JOINS and WHERE
    ) AS [Source] ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED AND [Source].somecolumn > 0 THEN
    INSERT 
        --columns to insert
    VALUES
        --their values
```

**EDIT**

Modified the statement to show the change according to the docs.

Comment: `insert into [target] select ... from [source] where somecolumn > 0` seems like a simpler approach?

Comment: `MERGE` when matched can only have an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement see [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: You don't need to use merge because no JOIN with [source] an INSERT SELECT statement is what you need

Comment: [Source].somecolumn > 0 can be used in "--Here SELECT and INNER JOINS and WHERE"

Comment: I'm using matched because I need to use OUPUT to output multiple columns into a table type.

Comment: @SebriZouhaier this is tagged `sql-server` - youve provided oracle docs.

Comment: sorry you don't specify wich SGBD you use so i think it is the Oracle MERGE

Comment: You need to provide a **meaningful** join condition - some column (or set of columns) to join the two data sets `Source` and `Target` on.... otherwise - how should the `MERGE` know **WHEN MATCHED** or **WHEN NOT MATCHED** ?? `ON 1=0` is a bit pointless - every row will be **not matched** ...... but that's most likely *not* what you're looking for....

Comment: @SebriZouhaier again, its tagged *microsoft* sql-server. Your comment is not only obsolete, it's confusing to a user of sql server.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono  `output` clause is applicable to `insert` statement as well.